# Values in array getting altered yet they shouldn't

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

It's a program that requires the user to enter the values of two 3 by 3 matrix then finds the sum of both matrices and prints out the same together with the added matrices but for some reason after entering the values of both matrices the a value in matrix gets altered then it affects the sum but at times it doesn't

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int matrix1[2][2];
    int matrix2[2][2];
    int sumMatrix[2][2];
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            printf("Matrix[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
            printf("Enter matrix one's values> ");
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
     for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            printf("Matrix[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
            printf("Enter matrix two's values> ");
            scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
     }
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        sumMatrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
            
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%d ", matrix1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");}
        printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%d ", matrix2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");}
        printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%d ", sumMatrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

}

}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){` generates 0,1,2, but in `int matrix1[2];` you only have room for 0,1.

Comment: Please don't post interactive programs as your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), unless you've isolated the problem to the I/O portion. I can't reproduce anything with a program like this unless you tell me the exact input necessary, and you could just hard-code that once you know it and halve the amount of code I have to read.

Comment: what input are you using and what output are you getting. check if `input` is greater than what int can hold. yes and matrix[size] should be used that is matrix[3][3] as pointed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring matrixes of size 2x2 and access them as if they were 3x3. What's happening more precisely is a buffer overflow, you write somewhere you shouldn't, and by doing so you overwrite other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Lad, that is array overflow.
`int matrix1[2][2];`
But in the loop, you may get matrix1[2][1], matrix1[2][2].

Answer (score 0):

Ok so clearly I'm the idiot. I thought array sizes are set based on the number of indices they'll have, so instead of `int matrix1[2][2]` it should be `int matrix [3][3]`

Comment: Don't answer to your post, add a comment to an answer instead, and only if it brings new information